# how does creating connection pool work with multiple clients request

Tags: python, database, http, database-connection, connection-pooling

I have been reading multiple resources on connection pooling and I'm confused at the most fundamental level here.

So say we initialized the pool object with script:

```
from mysql.connector import pooling

try:
    connection_pool = pooling.MySQLConnectionPool(pool_name="pynative_pool",
                                                  pool_size=1,
                                                  pool_reset_session=True,
                                                  host='localhost',
                                                  database='python_db',
                                                  user='pynative',
                                                  password='pynative@#29')
```

So as per my understanding application code runs anew for each client http request.

Hence this creation of pooling may be initialized again (?) with every new request.

How does this actually work? If anyone could enlighten me with this basics.